# How do I post JSON data to cart and checkout?

Tags: commerce, services, 8

I'm using Drupal commerce services for module for REST API calls, but I don't know how to post JSON to REST service cart and checkout.

The product attributes I have are *field_taxo_color* and *field_taxo_size*. How do I include the selected attributes?

The product list JSON is the following.

> [image: screenshot]